# What logic CPU applies to generate correct PageNumber and PageOffset?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, paging

As per my understanding, to access a page from physical memory, CPU generates PageNumber and PageOffset for the page requested. The logical PageNumber content then get replaced by physical PageNumber content from page table entries. Hence, the physical location of the page requested is PageNumber+PageOffset. So, how CPU already has the information about the Offset value?

Also, at the time of allocating a new page how CPU determines the offset value for the page to be allocated?

Comment: *"how CPU already has the information about the Offset value"* -- The page_offset is calculated by the MMU from the virtual address that caused the translation: `page_offset = virtual_addr % PAGESIZE`  Since the PAGESIZE is usually a power of two, the modulo operation can be replaced with a bit-wise AND: `page_offset = virtual_addr & (PAGESIZE - 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the translation from virtual memory to physical memory is made, not all of the bits in the address are replaced. The higher order bits of the virtual memory are indeed replaced with the physical address bits, but a certain number of the lower order bits are retained, and they correspond to the offset. The number of bits that identify the offset into the page will vary between architectures.

Take a look at this diagram:

[image: Address translation]

Legend:

- **p** Page number
- **f** Page base address
- **d** Displacement (or offset)

Note that the offset is not changed during address translation. Therefore, when the memory is retrieved by the CPU, no calculations are necessary - the offset is unchanged.

For your second question: when memory is allocated, a *whole page* is allocated and the CPU doesn't care about offsets into the page. Offsets only matter when a specific memory address (with its unchanged offset) is requested from the CPU.